# Error. C++. Expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program and met an error in **switch**. What is wrong?

Error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<string> myList;

    string s;
    while (true) {
        cin >> s;
        switch(s) {
            case "quit":
            break;

            default:
            myList.push_back(s);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `case "quit":` You cannot use `switch` with string literals or complex types in c++!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is here:

```
 switch(s) {
```

You cannot use `strings` in a switch case.

Alternative:

An if-else ladder. Since you have only one case, use an `if` statement for it. For example:

```
if (s=="quit") {
    break;
} 
else 
    myList.push_back(s);
```

Comment: _`strcmp()`, `strncmp()`_ OP already uses `std::string`, don't confuse them with that unrelated stuff. `strcmp(s,"quit")` would actually fail to compile in context of their code.